# Уведомить QAbstractTableModel об изменении data sourse

Tags: c++, qt, viewmodel

Возможно, данная тема обсуждалась большое количество раз, но я не смог найти однозначного ответа и рабочей реализации задачи.

Имеется модель, унаследованная от `QAbstractTableModel`. Модель редактируемая. Пользователь может изменять некоторые данные в ней, так же добавлять/удалять строки.

Источником данных выступает класс `Scanner` для каждой строки. Данные в объекте изменяются внутри. Вообще это отображение данных `api запросов`, но для примера написал некий счетчик, который обновляется по таймеру.

```
Scanner::Scanner(QObject * parent)
    : QObject (parent)
{
    auto timer = new QTimer();
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this] {
        this->setDifference(getDifference() + 1);
        emit dataChanged();
    });

    timer->start(1000);
}
```

Для каждой строки в `view` создается отдельный объект `Scanner`.

```
bool ScanningModel::insertRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    beginInsertRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1);

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        auto scanner = new Scanner();
        connect(scanner, &Scanner::dataChanged, this, [this] {
            emit beginResetModel();
            emit endResetModel();
        }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
        m_scanners.insert(position, scanner);
    }

    endInsertRows();
    return true;
}
```

Собственно **вопрос**: как уведомить модель о том, что данные в `Scanner` изменились и нужно их отобразить в `view`?

Вариант с `beginResetModel` и `endResetModel` работает. Но при этом модель сбрасывается и выделенная строка в `view` тоже. Т.е, чтобы внести изменения в строку через интерфейс, пользователю нужно успеть это сделать.

Для данной задачи предназначен сигнал в модели `dataChanged`. Но для него нужно передавать `QModelIndex`, которого нет в `Scanner` и сам `index` может изменится в любой момент (когда пользователь удалил/добавил новые строки).

Comment: beginResetModel и endResetModel таких сигналов в QAbstractTableModel нет

Comment: @AlexanderChernin ``QAbstractTableModel`` наследник ``QAbstractItemModel``. эти сигналы наследуются от ``QAbstractItemModel``

Comment: но это не сигналы, а защищенные функции )

Comment: @Alexander Chernin однако вы правы, не обратил внимание. спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде вы уведомили модель о том, что данные изменились: вы соединили сигнал `Scanner::dataChanged` с лямбда-слотом модели. Тут всё правильно. Стало быть, ваш вопрос в том, как уведомить *представление* о том, что данные изменились. И опять вы сами же ответили: сигналом `dataChanged` модели. Осталось понять, как сформировать левый верхний и правый нижний индексы.

Сигнал `dataChanged` имеет следующие параметры:

```
void QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged(const QModelIndex &topLeft, const QModelIndex &bottomRight, const QVector<int> &roles = ...)
```

Одним из способов решения (не буду утверждать, что самым оптимальным) будет добавить в класс `Scanner` числовое поле, показывающее номер строки. Например, так:

```
class Scanner : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    int m_rowNumber;
public:
    int rowNumber();
    void setRowNumber();
};
```

В модели при добавлении и удалении строк вам нужно будет правильно заполнять номер строк у созданных объектов, а также обновлять номера существующих объектов при их изменении. Когда вы это сделаете, у вас будут все необходимые данные для создания индекса. Тогда вы можете переписать ваш слот следующим образом:

```
connect(scanner, &Scanner::dataChanged, this, [this] {
    Scanner *scanner = sender();//Возвращает объект, который отправил сигнал
    dataChanged(index(scanner->rowNumber(), 0), index(scanner->rowNumber(), columnCount()));
}, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Я не проверял, будет ли работать метод `sender` в лямбда-функции. Но если не будет, вы можете вынести её в отдельный слот.

Comment: спасибо! работает отлично. я переживал, что вариант с пересчетом строк будет неудобным, но даже с использованием прокси-модели работает как нужно